# Priority of the 3 axioms of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

In my book about Abstract Algebra, it is stated that

> A **group** $\langle G,*\rangle$ is a set $G$, closed under a binary operation $*$, such that these 3 axioms are satisfied:
>
> - $g_1$: For  all $a,b,c\in G$, $$(a*b)*c=a*(b*c) $$
> - $g_2$: There  is an element $e$ in $G$ such that for all $x\in G$, $$e*x=x*e=e$$
> - $g_3$: Corresponding to $a\in G$, there is an element $a'$ such that $$a*a'=a'*a=e$$

The book stated  that among the 6 orders of $g_1,g_2,g_3$, only $3$ are correct orders of defining a group. But I have no idea about it. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: I don’t think it makes sense to quote $g_3$ before $g_2$.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Is there any significance in the order in which group axioms are presented?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181624/264), should we close it?

Comment: @Lubin I get it now.

Comment: But I doubt whether it's necessary to CHECK ALL the axioms. For instance, assuming $g_2$ is true, if we can proof that $g_3$ is false, G certainly isn't a group; if $g_2$ is false, then $G$ isn't a group, either.

Answer (score -1):

The author of your book is unnecessarly  delving into what order of stating axioms are useful.  A dictionary should simply list what are the words of that language.

Listing a cacaphony of letters that are not words of that language, even if logically correct, does not serve any useful purpose.